# Estimating the order of growth of running time of an alogrithm

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I am following the an online course and I can't understand well how to estimate the order of growth of an algorithm here s an example

What is the order of growth of the worst case running time of the following code fragment
as a function of N?

```
   Int sum = 0;
   For (int i = 1; i <= 4*N; i = i*4)
     for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
    sum++;
```

Can anyone explain to me how to get it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just calculate how many times the statement `sum++;` is executed.

= 1 + 4 + 16 + 64 ... + 4*N

This is a geometric progression with common factor of 4. If number of terms in this series is k, then

```
4^k = 4*N.

Sum of series = (4^k - 1)(4-1) = (4*N - 1)/3.
```

In order of growth we neglect the constant factors.

Hence the complexity is O(N).

Answer (score 1):

This is fairly straightforward:

There are `log(N) + 1` iterations of the outer loop (logarithm is base 4).

Let `x` be the outer loop iteration number. The inner loop iterates `4^x` times.

Hence the total runtime is `Sum(4 ^ x) for x in [0..c]`, where `c` is `log(N)` This is a [geometric series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Sum), and it's sum is easily calculated using the formula from the wiki:

`Sum(4 ^ x) for x in [1..c]` = `(1 - 4^c)/(1 - 4)` = `(4 ^ c)/3`. Now `c` is log(N) in base 4, hence `4^c = N`. The total answer is hence N with some constant factors.

Answer (score 1):

While finding order of algorithm we find the total number of steps that algorithm goes through

Here the innermost loop has the number of steps equal to current value of i.

Let i goes through values i1,i2,i3...in

So the total number of steps in the algorithm are ->> i1+i2+i3+ ...  in .

Here values of i1,i2,i3...in are 1,4,64...4N ; which is a GP with first term=a=1 and last term 
equal to 4N.So the complexity of this algorithm is sum of all terms in this GP.

SUM=1+4+64+...4N

sum of GP with n terms a,ar,ar^2...ar^(n-1)=a((r^n)-1)/(r-1)=a(L*r-1)/(r-1)
where L=last term;

Here in our case sum= 1*((4*4N)-1)/3
which is approximately 1.33 times the last term L
SUM=1.33*4N
which is linear order of N

Thus number of steps are linear function of N and
So the complexity of algorithm is of order N; i.e. O(n).