# How do I find the order of growth for this function?

Tags: java, time-complexity

Here's the function:

```
int sum = 0;
for (int n = N; n > 0; n /= 2)
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        sum++;
```

The order of growth they gave was O(n). So how did they get to that answer?

Comment: may this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25785291/estimating-the-order-of-growth-of-running-time-of-an-alogrithm)  help you.

Answer (score 3):

Time complexity of this function is the number of iteration:

```
Time complexity = sum = N + N/2 + N/4 + ... = N*(1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + ... + 1/(2^logN))
```

We know that, the infinite sequence `1/2 + 1/4 + ...` is a [convergent sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1/2_%2B_1/4_%2B_1/8_%2B_1/16_%2B_%E2%8B%AF), which converges to 1.

Applying the result to above formula: `sum <= N*(1 + 1) = 2*N ~ O(N)`

So, the time complexity of your function is bounded by `O(N)`

Comment: But this isn't true for example for `N = 10`.

Comment: @SubOptimal how? 10 + 5 + 2 + 1 <= 2*10, which is correct I guess?

Comment: But it's not linear. `N + N/2 + N/4 + ...`. Because of the rounding of `5/2`. I only wonder if it could be named as `O(n)` even it is not really linear. (if you would draw a graph with the relation of `N` and `sum` it would be not a straight line)

Comment: @SubOptimal According to my understanding, Big O doesn't need to be similar in graph form, here is what I found on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation): A description of a function in terms of big O notation usually only provides an **upper bound** on the growth rate of the function. You can also find a not-so-clear example on the above wiki link, which demonstrated a function f(x) and its O(g(x)).

Comment: I had a look at [Wikipedia: time complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity) which explains: `An algorithm is said to be constant time if the value of T(n) is bounded by a value that does not depend on the size of the input.`. Maybe I misunderstand it. That's why I'm a bit confused.

Comment: @SubOptimal I think you misunderstand it, as `constant time` is about `O(1)` time complexity, not `O(n)` . I guess because of the use of notation T(n), which can cause a lot of misconception in this context :)

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right, the explanation how to get the complexity of your example is:

The O-notation takes into account only the worst case scenarios (upper bounds). In the example those would be for `N` values which are power of two. The upper bound number of steps to be executed (in the example it would be equal to the increments of `sum`) can be computed as `2 * N - 1`. Which is a linear function. For no value of `N` more steps than `2 * N - 1` would need to be executed.

Your code snippet amended for demonstration.

```
for (int N = 1; N < 15; N++) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int n = N; n > 0; n /= 2) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            sum++;
        }
    }
    System.out.printf("N: %2d  steps: %2d   2n-1: %2d%n", N, sum, 2 * N - 1);
}
```

output

```
N:  1  steps:  1   2n-1:  1
N:  2  steps:  3   2n-1:  3
N:  3  steps:  4   2n-1:  5
N:  4  steps:  7   2n-1:  7
N:  5  steps:  8   2n-1:  9
N:  6  steps: 10   2n-1: 11
N:  7  steps: 11   2n-1: 13
N:  8  steps: 15   2n-1: 15
N:  9  steps: 16   2n-1: 17
N: 10  steps: 18   2n-1: 19
N: 11  steps: 19   2n-1: 21
N: 12  steps: 22   2n-1: 23
N: 13  steps: 23   2n-1: 25
N: 14  steps: 25   2n-1: 27
```

The number of steps is always lower or equal to `2 * N - 1`.